# Confusion about the difference between HN/N and H/N in the second isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Im trying to understand the second isomorphism theorem but I am stuck. So in my textbook the author did the following:

Let G be a group and N<G a normal subgroup and H<G a subgroup. Let $\pi: G\rightarrow G/N$ be the canonical homomorphism given by $g\mapsto gN$. If we limit this map to H, then we have homomorphism $H\mapsto G/N$ with kernel $H\cap N $ and image HN/N. I understand why the kernel is equal to $H\cap N$, but why is the image equal to HN/N?. What I think is the following: The homomorphism $H\rightarrow G/N$ is defined as $h\mapsto hN$ which means the image for the whole subgroup H is $H/N=\{hN|h\in H\}$. Now the problem is that N can not be a subgroup of H so H/N does not make sense. Is that the reason why we have HN/N instead, because they are the same set $HN/N=\{hnN|h\in H\}=\{hN|h\in H\}=H/N$ or are they not? If not what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

Consider an *actual example*:  $\pi : \mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z$ where $G  = \mathbf Z$ and $N = 24\mathbf Z$. Set $H = 10\mathbf Z$.  Here we're using additive groups, so the notation becomes additive ($H + N$ instead of $HN$). The image of $H$ is what you get by repeatedly adding $10$ to itself modulo $24$:
\begin{align*}
\{10, 20, 6, 16, 2, 12, 22, 8, 18, 4, 14, 0\} \bmod 24 & = \{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18\} \bmod 24 \\
& = 2\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z, 
\end{align*}
where $2\mathbf Z = 10\mathbf Z + 24\mathbf Z$ (since $2 = \gcd(10,24)$) $= H + N$, so the image of $\pi$ is $(H+N)/N$.
Would you call the image $H/N = 10\mathbf Z/24\mathbf Z$?

Answer (score 0):

You are of course correct that the image of ${\left.\pi\right|_H}$ is ${\{hN: h \in H\}}$, which is a subgroup of ${G/N}$ with group structure given by ${(hN)(h'N) = (hh')N}$. You could refer to this as ${H/N}$ if you like, but we tend to strictly reserve the notation of "${A/B}$" when $B$ is a sub-structure of $A$, which, as you point out, is not necessarily the case in this context.

If instead you consider the product group ${HN}$, then $N$ really is then a normal subgroup of ${HN}$, and so the notation ${(HN)/N}$ follows the standard convention mentioned above. Furthermore, ${(HN)/N}$ as a group is clearly the same as ${\{hN: h \in H\}}$ with the above mentioned product.

To summarise: we use ${(HN)/N}$ instead of ${H/N}$ to keep up with standard notation conventions.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really a "matter of taste," since as you stated the notation $H / N$ doesn't really mean anything unless $N$ is a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: @Frank The notation is meaningful if H is *any* subset of $G$.  That is, after all, how we denote individual cosets of $N$.

Comment: @RobertShore Are you referring to the notation $SN$ for a subset $S$? I’m talking about  the notation $S/N$, which I’ve only seen used when $S$ is a group (or other mathematical structure) containing $N$ as a subgroup (or substructure).

Comment: @Frank Any notation could have meaning if we decide to give it meaning, and I am saying in this context it certainly would make sense to, given a normal subgroup ${N}$ of $G$ and another subgroup (or even just subset, as Robert Shore above has said) $H$, to define ${H/N}$ as the set of cosets ${\{hN: h \in H\}}$; the point in what I was saying however was this notation is not used and we generally own use ${A/B}$ if $B$ is a substructure of $A$

Comment: @Frank With that being said, maybe saying it comes down to taste implies that there are a notable group of people who would use this notation, which is not the case. I'll edit my answer to reflect that